# How can I pass a variable from html to directive AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have an html and I neew to show a pop up. I have this:

```
<div class="dashboardTr" ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <modal-dashboard header="Success" body="post.ID" id="success"></modal-dashboard>
</div>
```

and this directive:

```
app.directive('modalDashboard', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            header: '@header',
            body: '=',
            id: '@id'
        },
        templateUrl: '/modalDashboard.html'
    }
});
```

The new HTML of the pop up is:

```
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">{{ header }}</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
              <p>{{ body }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. If I pass a string into the body property, it works. What's the problem? 
It is inside another directive. Could it be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by random word? Where are you passing random word?

Comment: I think it's conflicting with DOM in case of `body` and `header`, try changing it.

Comment: which binding exactly not happening on modal template?

Comment: @Hearty Nop, I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @PankajParkar Sorry I didn't say. The body = post.ID

Comment: show us your controller, how does $scope.posts look like?

Comment: @apieceofbart post.ID is the ID of the post. It works because if I write it in the first html inside of a p tag, it shows.

Comment: You would do well to provide a [mcve] for this question.

Comment: try `body="{{ post.ID }}"`

Comment: @xAqweRx Nop. It doesn't work.

Comment: It should work, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xy9koo0h/1/ 
My guess is there's something wrong with the rest of your code.

Comment: @Ary I doubt that `body` is not working, As I can see `header` & `id`(ideally id attribute should be used, rename it to something else) binding isn't working, because attribute value should pass in string format like `<modal-dashboard header="'Success'" body="post.ID" id="'success'"></modal-dashboard>`

Comment: I think problem not with directive problem is **ng-repeat**

Comment: @Sandeep I don't know why but if I write before the <modal-dashboard> <p>{{post.ID}}</p> It works

Comment: really @Ary. Your body parameter value not unique na?

Comment: @Sandeep It is unique

Comment: getting error or not?

Comment: @Sandeep nop, without errors...

Comment: can u give code of controller, Directive and template in plunkr...

Comment: @apieceofbart It is inside another directive. Could it be the problem?

Comment: @Ary could be. Are you able to modify fiddle I created to look similar to your code?

Comment: can u show your **body** object. like what parameter within body object

Comment: @Sandeep The first html is inside another directive. Could it be the problem?

Comment: @apieceofbart yes, I will try

Comment: @apieceofbart I tried in your fiddle page and it works...

Comment: @Ary great! now you only have to find out where's the difference:)

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
app.directive('modalDashboard', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        header: '@header',
        body: '=body', // <-- make sure to modify this to evaluate body attribute
        id: '@id'
    },
    templateUrl: '/modalDashboard.html'
}
});
```

Comment: No, I've tried this at first. The first html is inside another directive. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's mostly the reason

Comment: check a working demo to see it works here:
http://jsbin.com/levuhabeji/edit?html,output